# Wordpress lightbox not responsive (only on iphone)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

For wordpress (cherry frameworks)...

I'm using a shortcodes plugin called "Ultimate Shortcodes." One of the shortcodes is for a lightbox which can be called to display content. It works absolutely great everywhere except iPhone 4s and earlier. Any thoughts?

(view source)
[www.mbccs.com/ot3][1]

Comment: Can you please clarify where on that page the lightbox in question is?

Comment: No problem, mknadler. The lightbox comes up when you click on an of the individuals on the page (or the "read more" button below them).